# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-79%"

Tags: selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

Getting the error while converting discount value-79% to 79.

**for (int i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
String DiscountValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[" + i + "]/div/a/section/div/span")).getText();
System.out.println("Game Discount is :"+ DiscountValue);

```
        String str=DiscountValue;
        System.out.println(str.substring(1,3));
        
        int Discount = Integer.parseInt(DiscountValue);
        
        if (Discount >= 85) {
            String GameName=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/main[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/div[1]/a[1]/section[1]/span[1]")).getText();
            System.out.println("Please add to Wishlist:"+ GameName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Jump to next game" +i);
        }**
```

Comment: Hello, your code there is not formatted properly, please check the preview of your post before posting. And also its recommended to add the tag of the language you are using. Anyways have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion seems incorrect and that's why you are getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

> The NumberFormatException is thrown when we try to convert a string
> into a numeric value such as float or integer, but the format of the
> input string is not appropriate or illegal.

You are using `System.out.println(str.substring(1,3));` which had no effect on the actual value, as `String` is immutable. Also, you need to pass `str`
to `int Discount = Integer.parseInt(str);`

To solve and to fix this you need to use the below code:

**Complete Code:**

```
 String str = DiscountValue;
 str = str.substring(1, 3);
 int Discount = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

**Other way to parse String to Integer is:**

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```